# Size of equations

Tags: math-mode, align, article

How I can shrink the equations within an  align environment ?

Here it it my MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

% First Math Setup 


\begin{align}
\max_{\Delta_{t} } \mathbb{E}_{0} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} & \beta^{t+1} E_{t}[\log R_{x_{it+1}}] \label{ramsey_max_prob}\\
\text{s.t} \nonumber \\
 E_{t} \bigg[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}}(1  +(1- & \tau^k_{t+1})F_k(\theta^k_{t+1},\theta^h_{t+1}) - \delta)\bigg]  =  \nonumber \\
  E_{t} \bigg[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}} (1  +(1-& \tau^w_{t+1})F_h(\theta^k_{t+1},\theta^h_{t+1}) - \delta+ \eta^i_{t+1}) \bigg]   \qquad \forall t \label{con2}  \\[5 mm]
E_{t} \bigg[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}}(1  +(1-  \tau^k_{t+1})F_k(\theta^k_{t+1},\theta^h_{t+1}) - \delta)\bigg]  & =  E_{t} \left[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}} \right] R^f_{t}   \qquad \forall t \label{con4}  \\
 \text{Financial markets clearing:} \qquad & \phi_{t+1} + \theta^k_{t+1}  + \theta^h_{t+1}  = 1      \qquad \forall t \label{con5}\\
 \text{Budget Constraint:} \qquad & \phi_{t+1}\beta R_{x_t}   \leq R^f_{t-1}\phi_{t} + g_{t} -\tau^k_{t}F_{k}\theta^k_{t}  -\tau^w_{t}F_{H}\theta^h_{t}  \label{con6} \\
 \text{\textit{Ad hoc} borrowing constraint} \qquad & \underline{\mathcal{B}}  \leq R^f_{t}\phi_{t+1}\leq \overline{\mathcal{B}} \label{con7}
\end{align}

% Second math setup

\begin{align}
\mathcal{SL}_{k} \equiv \Psi_{2} \left(\mathrm{Cov}( m^i_{t+1},F_{k_{t+1}}) + \mathrm{Cov}( \frac{ \partial m^i_{t+1}}{\partial \tau^k_{t+1}},\mathcal{\tilde{P}}^K_{t+1}) \right) - \Psi_{1} \left(\mathrm{Cov}( m^i_{t+1},F_{k_{t+1}}) - \mathrm{Cov}( \frac{ \partial m^i_{t+1}}{\partial \tau^k_{t+1}},\mathcal{\tilde{P}}^H_{t+1}) \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Those equations look relatively large for the document class that I am using and I am wondering whether I can shrink them.

Comment: You should not start resizing formulas, they should be rebroken instread. Resizing will end up giving an uneven design that does not look professional

Answer (score 4):

Please do not shrink your formulae. Just distribute them better over the lines as has been shown a lot of times in this stack-exchange:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{Cov}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    \max_{\Delta_{t} } \mathbb{E}_{0} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^{t+1} E_{t}[\log R_{x_{it+1}}] \label{ramsey_max_prob}\\
    \shortintertext{s.t}
    \begin{split}
        E_{t} \bigg[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}}&(1  +(1- \tau^k_{t+1})F_k(\theta^k_{t+1},\theta^h_{t+1}) - \delta)\bigg]  =  \\
        &E_{t} \bigg[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}} (1  +(1- \tau^w_{t+1})F_h(\theta^k_{t+1},\theta^h_{t+1}) - \delta+ \eta^i_{t+1}) \bigg]   \qquad \forall t \label{con2}
    \end{split}\\
    E_{t} \bigg[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}}(1  +(1-  \tau^k_{t+1})F_k(\theta^k_{t+1},\theta^h_{t+1}) - \delta)\bigg] =  E_{t} \left[  R^{-1}_{ix_{t+1}} \right] R^f_{t}   \qquad \forall t \label{con4}
\end{gather}
\begin{align}
    \text{Financial markets clearing:} \qquad & \phi_{t+1} + \theta^k_{t+1}  + \theta^h_{t+1}  = 1      \qquad \forall t \label{con5}\\
    \text{Budget Constraint:} \qquad & \phi_{t+1}\beta R_{x_t}   \leq R^f_{t-1}\phi_{t} + g_{t} -\tau^k_{t}F_{k}\theta^k_{t}  -\tau^w_{t}F_{H}\theta^h_{t}  \label{con6} \\
    \text{\textit{Ad hoc} borrowing constraint:} \qquad & \underline{\mathcal{B}}  \leq R^f_{t}\phi_{t+1}\leq \overline{\mathcal{B}} \label{con7}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathcal{SL}_{k} &\equiv \Psi_{2} \biggl[\cov( m^i_{t+1},F_{k_{t+1}}) + \cov\biggl( \frac{ \partial m^i_{t+1}}{\partial \tau^k_{t+1}},\mathcal{\tilde{P}}^K_{t+1}\biggr) \biggr] \\
        &\quad - \Psi_{1} \biggl[\cov( m^i_{t+1},F_{k_{t+1}}) - \cov\biggl( \frac{ \partial m^i_{t+1}}{\partial \tau^k_{t+1}},\mathcal{\tilde{P}}^H_{t+1}\biggr) \biggr]
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as you probably know, it's not recommended to string multiple instances of `equation` one after another.  i can see "breaking" between nos.(3) and (4), but the first three could very well be handled by `gather` with (2) `split` as shown, and the "s.t." inserted with `\shortintertext` (requires `mathtools`, which you're already using).

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, I've corrected that. I was not too sure about the final layout of this page, but you are absolutely right about my example. And I did not know, that `\shortintertext` may go into `gather`.